# Add external python packages to iOS app (Swift, PythonKit)

Tags: python, ios, swift, xcode, swift-pythonkit

I have an iOS application in Swift.

I was following this video and this usage guide to install Python inside my iOS app:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gznPQpZH1Yc&ab_channel=EuroPythonConference
- https://github.com/beeware/Python-Apple-support/blob/main/USAGE.md

So now I can create .py files in my Resouces/Python/Resources folder, and run python functions.

But I have problems when I want to **import external packages**:

```
import cv2 <-------(!)
import os  <-------(!)
from image_similarity_measures.quality_metrics import rmse, ssim, sre <------- (!)

def myFunc():
    image = cv2.imread("/Users/user/Desk......<my path>...")

.............................
..... other logic steps .....
.............................
```

Obviously, xCode  returns me an error, because I didn't install external packages:

```
PythonKit/Python.swift:706: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Python exception: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (myscript.py, line 6)
```

I know that **I can't** just **pip install ...**

How to install 3-part python frameworks inside my Swift project?

Comment: That Python error is not about the missing packages. It looks like some sort of indentation problem.

Comment: And you can use `pip install`. Specify the `-root <directory>` option. If the packages are in the same directory as your python script, it might be ok.

Comment: where is root directory?  /Users/user/Desktop/myapp/Resources/Python/Resources ? I tried, and get an error: zsh: command not found: pip

Comment: https://youtu.be/gznPQpZH1Yc?t=2547 - Łukasz said that it is not available to pip install